# Is it possible to read data from firebase without an event listener?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple android application that I created using xamarin. I want to retrieve information from a specific location in my data base whenever a user press a certain button. I'm using the real time database. Is this possible?

I searched online for a few hours but I only found information about how to retrieve data when the data changes, I just need to retrieve it when a button is pressed.

![The structure of my database for context][1]

I want to retrieve the strings from a specific ID when a user presses a certain button. How do I retrieve the strings?

EDIT: I followed the advice of one of the comments that provided me with a java code, I'm trying to create a c# equivalent that i can use in xamarin, this is what I have so far:

```
  btnSearch.Click += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    DatabaseReference dbref = AppDataHelper.GetDatabase().GetReference("trip");
                    dbref.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
                    void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
                    {
                        if (args.DatabaseError != null)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.DatabaseError.Message);
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                };
```

ValueChanged and ValueChangedEventArgs aren't recognized, what should I do?

EDIT 2: I ended up using an event listener, when the event listener is initialized it retrieves data from the firebase.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrSDt.jpg

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't found a method that allows me to read date from the data base without a certain event happening so I haven't tried any. I will add some info to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I only found information about how to retrieve data when the data changes, I just need to retrieve it when a button is pressed.

From the Firebase documentation on [listening for events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#listen_for_events) (emphasis mine):

> You can use the ValueChanged event to subscribe on changes of the contents at a given path. **This event is triggered once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including children, changes.

So when you attach a listener, it immediately gets the current value from the server and triggers your callback with that.

---

To [read a value with a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#read_data_once), you can use `GetValueAsync`. I'm not sure if the Xamarin library has that though, as it wasn't created by Firebase - as far as I know.

Comment: thank you for your response, I'm struggling to create a xamarin equivalent for the code snippet that you provided, could you help me with that as well? I will add what I have so far to my question since the character limit is too small.